# How to distinguish between a found 0 and default(int) when using methods like FindLast?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of integers and I need to find the last occurrence that matches a predicate. To use a very simple example:

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 5, 6, 20, 18, 2, 3, 0, 4 };
var lastMatch = myList.FindLast(e => e == 0 || e == 2);
```

This seems like the perfect usecase for `FindLast`. Problem is that this method returns `default(T)` if nothing was found, which in the case of integers, is actually a valid value `0`. So the question is, if this method returns `0`, how can I know if it found something or not? Is there a better method for this case with ints?

Comment: You could combine with `.Contains()` or use `List<int?>` so that default is `null` instead of `0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `FindLastIndex` instead. If the index is negative no match was found. If it isn't negative: that's the index you want, so: use the indexer with that index.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @MarcGravell answer:
Instead of the List `FindLast` method, you could use the Linq `Last` extension method overload that takes a predicate as an argument. It will throw an exception if no match is found.

See [Last documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.last?view=net-6.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Last__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__)

Comment: True, but then you have to deal with the exception. If you know there's a possibility the item can't be found, it's not really exceptional to not find it. `LastOrDefault` might be the better choice in that case. Either way, you have to do some intermediate check against something but an exception would be my last choice.

Comment: Obviously you have to deal with the exception... But I fail to see what the use or `LastOrDefault` would bring, since it would mimic exactly the `FindLast` behaviour.

Comment: Well it wouldn't in this case with integers and therefore Marc's answer is the better approach. I was speaking to the general use of `Last` and forcing exceptions and handling in your code when you're doing something that is expected. By definition that's not exceptional.

Comment: I don’t think the OP stated that the fact that "nothing was found" was a normal case or an exceptional one, so I disagree with your interpretation. It could be exceptional, and then throwing an exception would be obviously relevant.

Comment: "This seems like the perfect usecase for FindLast." In other words, they don't expect to get an exception like you suggest because it returns a default value which, in this case, is problematic for them.

Comment: I suppose this does still remove the ambiguity which was the main problem. But note that `Last` should only be used if you wanted to assert that there should be something to find and that failing to find something indicates a programming error.

Answer (score 1):

In *general case* when we have `IEnumerable<T>` with *arbitrary* `T` (we can't play trick with `int?` now)
we can implement an *extension method*:

```
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static int LastIndex<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                        Predicate<T> predicate) {
      if (source is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
      if (predicate is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
 
      int result = -1;
      int index = -1;

      foreach (T item in source) {
        index += 1;

        if (predicate(item))
          result = index;
      }

      return result;
    }
  }
```

And then

```
var lastMatch = myList.LastIndex(e => e == 0 || e == 2);
```